# Почему не выводится textContent?

Tags: javascript

К примеру имеем обычные параграфы

```
<p>str1</p>
<p>str2</p>
<p>str3</p>
<p>str4</p>
```

Я хочу получить значения внутри этих параграфов и пытаюсь это сделать так

```
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var texts = selectors.textContent;
```

Потом [согласно описанию функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) делаю так

```
 var arr = texts.split(" ,");
```

Вывожу в консоль результат и получаю вот это

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как же это Вы `.textContent` берёте сразу со списка?

Вот так вот можно:

```js
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var arr = [];

selectors.forEach(function(element) {
  arr.push(element.textContent);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<p>str1</p>
<p>str2</p>
<p>str3</p>
<p>str4</p>
```

Comment: а бывают ещё способы получить содержимое ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Можно ещё `element.innerHTML`. В данном примере вернет то же самое. В более сложных случаях, когда внутри HTML-блоки -  может быть более подходящим...

Comment: NodeList не имеет методов кроме forEach да ?

Comment: до меня дошло ..спасибо !

Comment: @MaximLensky в новых браузерах появился forEach, но в старых нет. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach